# I can't show data from a local API

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js, fetch

I need to convert a PHP project to NodeJS, and I already have the API done without errors. The problem is when I want to fetch that data from the front-end, it returns me nothing than 404 errors. When I copy and paste the code in the browser console it works fine.

**Server.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const { Sequelize } = require('sequelize');
const path = require('path');


app.use(express.json());

// Conexion
const sequelize = new Sequelize('interaccion', 'carlos', 'CARLOSpsp1', {
    host: 'localhost',
    dialect: 'mysql'
});


app.get('/', (req,res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(`${__dirname}/client/index.html`));
});

app.get('/ejes', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        await sequelize.authenticate();
        console.log('Conexion exitosa');
        const [result, metadata] = await sequelize.query("SELECT * FROM ejes");
        return res.json(result);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Hubo un error: ', error);
    }
});


const puerto = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.listen(puerto,() => console.log(`Servidor en el puerto: ${puerto}`));
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hola mundo desde index</h1>

    <div id="container" class="container">

    </div>

    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**main.js**

```
let container = document.getElementById("id");
let div = document.createElement("div");

const fetchData = async () => {
    try{
        const res = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/ejes");
        const roles = await res.json();
        console.log(roles);
        roles.forEach(rol => {
            console.log(rol);
        });
    }catch(e){
        console.log("Error", e);
    }
}


window.onload = fetchData;
```

**Response from the route /ejes**
[image]

**console outputs**
[image]

Comment: there is no "https://localhost:3000/main.js"  routes in server.js you only have "/" and "/ejes"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It shows a 404 error for main.js.

Your server has:

- `app.get('/', (req,res) => {`
- `app.get('/ejes', async (req, res) => {`

… there's no route for `main.js` so why do you expect it to provide anything but a 404 Not Found error?

The express documentation [explains how to serve static files](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html), or you can use the same pattern as your `/` route.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that, you didn't specify the client static files. The static file includes all your javascript, css, images and other static resources.

setup the static resource folder from which the client can request the resource, else express will try to match the specific route. (which you don't have it)

Static resource configuration

```
app.use(express.static("client"));
```